# Finding Difficulty in adding Page numbersto pdf without using itext using java

Tags: java, pdf

I am having difficulty in adding page numbers to a pdf.

There are several files which will get converted to pdf at the end, the files may be:

- Docx
- html
- etc

At the end depending on the system only certain pdf files are combined together. While this process it is very tedious to track the page numbers.

Finally I want page numbers to be printed on bottom of the page including total number of pages EX: page 1 of 10

I have succeed in putting page numbers but we cannot track them.

Is there a way to apply it on an existing PDF?

I have tried using Itext sharp which is possible but I am looking for other software then itext sharp

I am  new to stack overflow please forgive if my approach  is wrong

Comment: apache pdfbox is a pretty good library for pdf manipulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i have understood from your explanation that i assume there are some files which gets merged finally on to pdf ther you have a bundle pdf

So I have an approach where you can add the page numbers directly once you finish your process.
Just input your final pdf you will get page numbers as expected.

```
import com.lowagie.text.Element;

import com.lowagie.text.pdf.BaseFont;

import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;

import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader;

import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfStamper;



public class AddPageNumbersToExistingPageNumberPDF {



        public static void main(String[] args) {

               try {

                     PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("d:\\3\\input.pdf" );

                      int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();

                     PdfStamper stamp = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(

                                   "d:\\3\\outup.pdf"));

                      int i = 0;

                     PdfContentByte pdf_over;

                     BaseFont bf = BaseFont. createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA,

                                  BaseFont. WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

                      while (i < n) {

                           i++;

                           pdf_over = stamp.getOverContent(i);

                           pdf_over.beginText();

                           pdf_over.setFontAndSize(bf, 18);

                            // width,height

                           pdf_over.setTextMatrix(500, 30);

                           pdf_over.showText( "PDF-Page " + i + " of " + n);// Format your

                                                                                                              // page number

                           pdf_over.setFontAndSize(bf, 32);

                           pdf_over.showTextAligned(Element. ALIGN_LEFT, "s          s",

                                         230, 430, 45);

                           pdf_over.endText();

                     }

                     stamp.close();

              } catch (Exception de) {

                     de.printStackTrace();

              }

       }

}
```

You can format your style of printing with this code as well.
Thank you.!!

Comment: This worked well ,It even reduced the work of tracking page numbers.